# undefined symbol: polkit_unix_process_new on i386 platform

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, packaging, dynamic-linking, vala

I'm packaging a debian vala application that uses `polkit` on both `i386` and `amd64`

I built my .deb files with `debuild` and the packaging went fine.

The installation is also fine on both platform. While everything is works as expected on `amd64`, the application fails to launch on `i386` with the following error:

```
undefined symbol: polkit_unix_process_new
```

I tried to install `libpolkit-gobject-1-dev` just in case this was a missing dependency but it doesn't change a thing.

Here's a copy of the debian control file in case that's relevant:

```
Source: elementary-tweaks
Section: x11
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Michael P. Starkweather <mpstark@gmail.com>
Build-Depends: cmake (>= 2.8),
               debhelper (>= 9),
               libgranite-dev,
               libgtk-3-dev (>= 3.10),
               libglib2.0-dev,
               libgee-0.8-dev,
               libgconf2-dev,
               libswitchboard-2.0-dev,
               libpolkit-gobject-1-dev,
               valac (>= 0.22)
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
Homepage: https://launchpad.net/elementarytweak

Package: elementary-tweaks
Architecture: any
Depends: gala, plank, slingshot-launcher, ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6)
Recommends: plank
Enhances: switchboard
Description: Change hidden desktop settings
 Switchboard plug for controlling hidden options.

Package: elementary-tweaks-dbg
Architecture: any
Section: debug
Priority: extra
Depends: elementary-tweaks (= ${binary:Version}), ${misc:Depends}
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6)
Enhances: elementary-tweaks
Description: Change hidden desktop settings (debugging symbols)
 Switchboard plug for controlling hidden options.
 .
 This package contains debugging symbols for switchboard-plug-template.
```

The complete code source of the application can be found [here](https://github.com/I-hate-farms/elementary-tweaks)

**edit** when I build the application on a i386 platform, the compilation and linking runs fine but it fails to launch with the same error, so this is not necessarily a packaging error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the error was a simple `cmake` error but not necessarily easy to spot when you are maintaining an application.

**It seems that `amd64` is generous enough to let the build error slide but not `i386`**

The issue was in the `cmake` file where the library `polkit-gobject-1` was missing in the `pkg_check_modules` clause *and* the include file was added manually **but** not the link to the shared library.

Erroneous cmake snippet:

```
pkg_check_modules (DEPS REQUIRED gthread-2.0 gtk+-3.0 switchboard-2.0 granite gconf-2.0 gee-0.8 glib-2.0)

add_definitions (${DEPS_CFLAGS} -I/usr/include/polkit-1) 
add_definitions (${DEPS_CFLAGS})
link_libraries (${DEPS_LIBRARIES})
link_directories (${DEPS_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Correct cmake snippet:

```
pkg_check_modules (DEPS REQUIRED gthread-2.0 gtk+-3.0 switchboard-2.0 granite gconf-2.0 gee-0.8 polkit-gobject-1 glib-2.0)

add_definitions (${DEPS_CFLAGS})
link_libraries (${DEPS_LIBRARIES})
link_directories (${DEPS_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```